PostgreSQL Power function
According to postgres documentation where are two power function interfaces:
power ( a numeric, b numeric ) → numeric
power ( a double precision, b double precision ) → double precision

However when testing with different types some wierd things happend:
select ( power( (1 + 0.1689), (32/365.0) )) as power_base,                             -- 1.01377627781508836023 - numeric
       ( power( (1 + 0.1689) :: numeric(22,7)   , (32/365.0) :: double precision )) as power_num_dp,  -- 1.0137762778150883 - double precision
       ( power( (1 + 0.1689) :: double precision, (32/365.0) :: numeric(22,7)    )) as power_dp_num,  -- 1.0137762726135617 - double precision
       ( power( (1 + 0.1689) :: numeric(22,7)   , (32/365.0) :: numeric(22,7)    )) as power_num_num, -- 1.0137762726135616 - numeric
       ( power( (1 + 0.1689) :: double precision, (32/365.0) :: double precision )) as power_dp_dp,   -- 1.0137762778150883 - double precision

You can see what there is extra 4 digits in the power_base value, hovewer pg_typeof() shows it's numeric. Also, when mixing double precision with numeric types - power_dp_num result a little different from power_num_num, I guess it could be rounding error for 1.1689 on numeric autocast .
So I tested it in PG13 and PG16 with PgAdmin and DBeaver and results are the same.

Nothing weird is going on. The fraction, (32/365.0), doesn't have an exact representation with a finite number of bits; therefore, the calculations are being performed with different values. The following query demonstrates value differences that result from type conversion:
SELECT
  (32 / 365.0::NUMERIC) AS num_value,
  (32 / 365.0::DOUBLE PRECISION) AS dp_value,
  (32 / 365.0::NUMERIC) - (32 / 365.0::DOUBLE PRECISION)::NUMERIC AS conversion_delta;




num_value
dp_value
conversion_delta




0.08767123287671232877
0.08767123287671233
0.00000000000000002877



DOUBLE PRECISION values are inexact with ~15 decimal digits of precision, and NUMERIC values can have up to 16363 digits after the decimal point (see 8.1. Numeric Types). Mixing NUMERIC and DOUBLE PRECISION values causes implicit type conversions.

But what is default precision/scale for not specified "numeric", I can see that scale is 20 in this case. Docs says it's up to the implementation limits, hovewer every example in 9.3. Mathematical Functions and Operators have only 16.

@Ice2burn, neither precision nor scale have a default: declaring a NUMERIC without precision and scale creates an unconstrained NUMERIC that can expand to the implementation limites. Run WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT 1 AS d, 1.1::NUMERIC AS v UNION SELECT cte.d + 1 AS d, FLOOR(v) * 10 + (v - FLOOR(v)) / 10::NUMERIC AS v FROM cte WHERE cte.d < 32 ) SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY d;  for a demonstration of how an unconstrained NUMERIC expands as additional digits are needed.
